# Equality override issue

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding, equality

I'm new to Python and I'm confused as to why I'm getting an override error. I'm trying to build a class network and representing it as dictionary which is represented by a BST. The keys in the dictionary are either a Student object with the value a list of courses, or a course (string) with the value being a list of students. The problem is that when analyzing if the course is in the dictionary, it keeps using the equality of the Student class despite being a string object.

Comment: You most probably want to `return False` if a `Student` doesn't match a string. Currently you're only using `assert`, thus why an `AssertionError` is thrown when the comparison returns `False`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It fixed my problem.

Comment: I've repeated my answer below - it would be great if you could mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `return False` rather than using `assert`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if type(other) != type(self):
        return False
    if (self.lastname == other.lastname and self.firstname == other.firstname and self.favcolor == other.favcolor):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Using `assert` will thrown an `AssertionError` if the comparison return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Seaman has mentioned `assert` raises `AssertionError` if the asserted condition is false. When that happens, an error message is printed and your program is terminated. You probably *don't* want that to happen. ;) Instead, you should put the type check of `other` as the first term in your equality test, as shown below.

The `assert` statement should *not* be used for testing the validity of data. Assertions are intended to catch flaws in the program's logic: if an `assert` test fails that's supposed to indicate that your program's logic is wrong and you need to fix it.

Rather than doing type testing with the `type` function, it's better to use `isinstance`, eg

```
if isinstance(other, Student):
```

It's also more flexible: if `other` is a class that's derived from `Student` the test will pass.

Don't do

```
if some_condition: 
    return True 
else: 
    return False
```

Instead, use this much more compact version:

```
return some_condition.
```

If `some_condition` isn't actually a boolean (`False` or `True`) and you actually *need* the function to return a boolean you may do

```
return bool(some_condition)
```

to convert it into a boolean, but that's generally not necessary.

Also, it appears that you're still using Python 2. You should define your classes to inherit from `object`, otherwise you get old-style classes rather than the superior new-style classes (in Python 3 all classes are new-style, so you don't need to explicitly inherit from `object`).

There's room for improvement in you `Student.__repr__` method. It appears that all the `Student` instance attributes (`lastname`, `firstname`, and `favcolor`) are strings, so there's no need to call `str` on them. You *can* concatenate strings using `+`, but it's often more convenient to use the `.format` or `.join` methods. Also, `__repr__` is intended for programmer use, and ideally it should return a string that can be used to re-construct the object; use `__str__` to create a user-friendly string. (If a class defines `__repr__` but doesn't define `__str__` then `__repr__` is used when you call `str` on the object).

Here's an improved version of your `Student` class which runs on both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, lastname, firstname, favcolor):
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.favcolor = favcolor

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, Student) and self.lastname == other.lastname 
            and self.firstname == other.firstname and self.favcolor == other.favcolor)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Student({!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(self.lastname, self.firstname, self.favcolor)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.firstname, self.lastname)

# test

students = [
    Student('Smith', 'John', 'red'),
    Student('Jones', 'Fred', 'blue'),
    'not a student',
]

for s1 in students:
    print(s1)
    for s2 in students:
        print('    {!r} : {}'.format(s2, s1 == s2))
```

**output**

```
John Smith
    Student('Smith', 'John', 'red') : True
    Student('Jones', 'Fred', 'blue') : False
    'not a student' : False
Fred Jones
    Student('Smith', 'John', 'red') : False
    Student('Jones', 'Fred', 'blue') : True
    'not a student' : False
not a student
    Student('Smith', 'John', 'red') : False
    Student('Jones', 'Fred', 'blue') : False
    'not a student' : True
```